# Error when deploy experience bundle community using Ant migration tool

Tags: community, experience-builder-page, deployment-api, experience-bundle, custom-theme-layout

I am deploying the community experience bundle using Ant migration tool and I am receiving the following error.

**themes/buildYourOwn.json needs to be a Theme Layout Component. Update the file and try again.**

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to get around your issue? Having the same thing.

Comment: We have the same problem intermittently. It will fail to work for a day or two then it will work fine for a while. The components mentioned are already in the org and have existed for a year or more and we don't include them again in the deployments.

Comment: No. I still having this issue. So we deployed through git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you have a custom aura/LWC theme component but it wasn't part of the package or not already deployed in the org or doesnt implement forceCommunityThemelayout.

Search the buildYourOwn.json file for componentName and check if there are any custom components usually will be like c: and make sure that component is having implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" (for aura) or having target lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout (for lwc).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this but still the same issue I received

Answer (score 1):

In case of deploying to a **scratch org** when facing the same error message, it helped to use the -f switch of the force:source:push command:

`$ sfdx force:source:push -fg`

Comment: This question isn't about sfdx, but rather the ANT migration tool (the thing we had prior to sfdx)

Comment: Alright, the thing is that i always came to this threat while searching for a solution for exactly the same problem, only with SFDX. To give other people using sfdx a hint, i dropped this line. But basically -- you are right.